# Exact solution of a BVP of second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems, fractional-calculus

Im solving a BVP which is $y^{\prime\prime}(t)=-y^{\prime2}(t)+y(t)(y^{2}(t)-\frac{3}{2}y(t)+\frac{1}{2})$ with boundary conditions $y(0)=1$  and $y(1)=2$. I need to find the exact solution for this BVP. I tried some numrical procedures to find its approximate solution for $t=0.5$ but failed.

Comment: What exactly did you try, I get with standard means a very nice solution with $y(0.5)$ very close to $1.5$, in general the solution is very close to $y(x)\approx 1+x$.

Comment: If you are looking for simplifications to try, note that $(e^y)''=e^y(y''+y'^2)$. But that should not be necessary.